# unable to open file with php on ubuntu machine

Tags: php, ubuntu, fopen

I trying to create new file in Ubuntu system using PHP script,
but when I run this script the error

```
Unable to Open file
```

is appear 
although I sure that the file's path is right and I have permissions to access this file I don't know where is the wrong 
this is my code

```
$myfile = fopen('inc/users/future.php', "w")or die("Unable to open file!") ;
$text='<?
$host ="'.$host.'";
 $user ="'.$db_admin.'" ;
 $pass ="'.$db_password.'";
 $db ="'.$database.'" ;
$myconn;?>';fwrite($myfile, $text);
fclose($myfile);
```

the path of this script is

> /var/www/html/ghost/index.php

and the path of the file which I wish to open is

> /var/www/html/ghost/inc/users/future.php

in other hand when I run this script in windows machine every thing is go fine

Comment: How do you run that script? And how did you check that you have enough permissions to manipulate that file?

Comment: Make sure the permissions on the file are set so your webserver has access to it.

Comment: how can I set permession to webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script use

```
fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/users/future.php', 'w')
```

This will create a filepath from the directory your index.php. If you script is called from another file, php might search coming from that file.

Also check if the php process has sufficient [file permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) to read and open the file. Try setting the file to `chmod 777` just to test if that is the case (do not leave it on 777 though).

Keep in mind that if the file is a symbolic link, the 'w' parameter of fopen will not work.

Comment: I have this in apache log file                                                                                                  "fopen(future.php): failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable in /var/www/html/in$"